# Select statement assistance

Tags: sql

I am not sure the exact terminologies to describe my concern so I will just provide examples:

The content of my table is:

```
ID  OPERATION_TYPE
1   Data A
2   Data A
3   Data A
4   Data A
1   Data B
```

If I use **SELECT ID, OPERATION_TYPE FROM TABLE_ASSN WHERE OPERATION_TYPE != 'Data B'**, it will only result to:

```
ID  OPERATION_TYPE
1   Data A
2   Data A
3   Data A
4   Data A
```

But my main objective is to remove all ID which has a **Data B** on **OPERATION_TYPE** column.

***My desired output is:***

```
ID  OPERATION_TYPE
2   Data A
3   Data A
4   Data A
```

Any assistance or notes that I should look into to get the desired query is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    OPERATION_TYPE
FROM 
    TABLE_ASSN
WHERE 
    ID NOT IN (
            SELECT
                ID
            FROM 
                TABLE_ASSN
            WHERE 
                OPERATION_TYPE = 'Data B'
        )
```

Comment: Thanks! This query is correct.  Though I can't accept this answer for it has cooldown or something?  Anyway, the question is closed.  Thank you again!

Comment: @ChiSen glad i could help. Both answers (from me and Amit) were valid.

Answer (score 7):

Use this

```
Select ID,OPERATION_TYPE FROM TABLE_ASSN WHERE ID not in
(SELECT ID FROM TABLE_ASSN WHERE OPERATION_TYPE = 'Data B')
```

OR Use as

```
Select ID,OPERATION_TYPE FROM TABLE_ASSN WHERE ID in
(SELECT ID FROM TABLE_ASSN WHERE OPERATION_TYPE! = 'Data B')
```

Comment: i think you meant `OPERATION_TYPE = 'Data B'` right?

Comment: That was a quick response!  But this query returned no result.

Comment: It's ok now, I forgot to refresh the page before I responded into your answer.  So I got the first answer earlier, then used the edited answer and everything is working perfectly as expected.  Thank you!